# Export acronyms to HTML with org-ref

Tags: org-mode, org-export, org-ref

Org-ref works quite nicely with acronyms in latex export and offer some niceties such as showing expansion on mouse hover and jump to the acronym on click. But it does not seem to export to html at all. It just make whatever was used as label for the acronym to upper case. For instance, the document below

```
#+LATEX_HEADER: \usepackage{glossaries}
#+latex_header_extra: \newacronym{aaa}{PC}{personal computer}
#+OPTIONS: toc:nil

  
Some text using ac:aaa.
```

exports to

> Some text using personal computer (PC).

in PDF (with latex), but to

> Some text using AAA.

in HTML, which is just

```
<p>
Some text using AAA.
</p>
```

It would be nice if org-ref (or org-mode, since I'm not sure where the export code handling the `ac:` link is) exported the acronym using the actual short acronym, instead of the label, and respected the capitalization of the acronym (not just put everything uppercase). Even better if it could export as something like

```html
<p>
    Some text using <abbr title="personal computer" >PC</abbr>.
</p>
```

---

Note: The `newacronym` command arguments are the label, the short acronym, and the long acronym.